# Exception: The recurrence interval for an Add-on trigger must be at least one hour

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Exception: The recurrence interval for an Add-on trigger must be at least one hour.

got this error when i published a standalone script as an sheet add-on 
i have a time driven  trigger which is causing this exception.

Comment: ...set the interval to more than 1 hour?

Comment: that is too much for me i can set an interval only for 5 mins. IS there any way to create.?

Answer (score 2):

Time-driven triggers in add-ons can only be run at most [once per hour](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). The rules for project triggers and add-on triggers are not the same. In this case, one hour is going to be the minimum recurrence rate that google will allow.

Answer (score 0):

Make your project a web app or run it from the script editor for intervals down to a minute.